# Should I pull triplex 4/0 though conduit before laying it in the trench?

Tags: wiring

I am going to be pulling some Triplex 4/0 4/0 2/0 though 2 1/2" conduit. Do you think I should pull it before putting it in the trench to make it easier? The trench is pretty much straight, with slight curve in beginning and end.

Answer (score 7):

### Assemble and bury the conduit. THEN pull wire.

You have to fully assemble the conduit, have it inspected if your inspector requires that, backfill it and - important - tamp it, especially the corners.  All BEFORE you start pulling any wires into it.

First-time conduit novices always think it will be "easier" to lay all the wire out and thread the conduit sticks over the wire.  I do a ton of conduit, and that doesn't sound "easier" at all, it sounds like the most difficult possible way to do it!  It really works much better to pull!  Of course, if that skill isn't in your repertoire *yet,* I can understand that -- I myself am terrified of drywall work.

What tends to coexist with the "assemble the conduit around the wires" way of thinking, is also a dastardly plan to build conduit in a way it would be impossible to pull.  For instance, using a plumbing elbow instead of a proper sweep, facing the LB against the wall so the access door can't be opened later, etc.   That's not allowed, and realistically, you'll hate yourself later if you do it.

Now, if you are using cable that is certified to be used *alone* (in walls or underground), then it is allowed to use conduit selectively, solely as a damage shield to protect certain segments of the cable run.  An example is when you do *direct burial*, and you are required to use a stick and a sweep of conduit simply to protect the wires on the "Stub-up".  In that case yeah, you thread conduit over cable, *but it's only a stick or two*.  If you have used conduit *like that* before, then I can understand that thinking.   And if you want to do that, then simply trench to 26" instead of 21" and just do direct burial.  Easy peasy. (however you will never be able to change or upgrade the wire, and that may be a huge problem because...)

Generally, when running conduit the entire route, you want to run THWN or XHHW individual wires.  Cables are much stiffer (the same way a ream of copier paper is stiff until you take the wrapper off, then, it's a noodle).  This also lets you select exactly the sizes you want, as selection is better in individual wires.

### Why are you running triplex anyway?

In almost all cases, triplex is the wrong stuff. Triplex is only allowed between the weatherhead, through the meter, and to the very first breaker or disconnect.  Beyond that, everything must be quadplex - separate neutral and ground.

Now some say "But the meter is out at a pole, and this is the run between meter and house".  Sure, except didn't the power company/inspector *require* you to have a main disconnect out at the pole?  I bet they did.  Then it needs to be 4-wire.

Comment: This wire is coming from power company transformer to a 200 amp meter/ distribution panel. That’s why it’s triplex direct bury but in conduit. No ground is needed. Only 2 grounding rods at panel

Comment: Thanks for the opinion about pulling wire. Just saw it done and seemed to work. They had conduit assembled and clued next to the trench, vacuum pulled a line though. Pulled wire, then put in trench.

Comment: The entire conduit run between panels or junction boxes needs to be complete, fastened down, backfilled and tamped before you start pulling.  Pulling forces can be considerable and could break or pull the conduits apart.

Comment: It's a straight shot accept where the sweep coming up to panel and into transformer. Wouldn't it be ok to glue, bury and stamp the straight sections, pull wire and then put on sweeps and connect to panel? Seems like having it connected to panel and feeding wire 4/0 4/0 2/0 wire though the panel adapter creates more work and possible damage to panel while doing it.

Comment: It would still be a code violation, but I'm wondering why you think that?  It seems harder to me, I just don't see how the endgame would work... when the sweep, stub-up and adapter are over the wires, how do you get it though the knockout in the panel?  Last time I tried that it was a nightmare, and that was with #12 wire...

Comment: @Dean Damage to wires, particularly from PVC cement, is amongst the reasons. The prohibition is against assembling conduit around the wires.  Only. You can pull wires into the 90% of the conduit that is complete, and assemble the last 10% around the pulling rope (still seems like 'the hard way' to me)...  If you want to change NEC talk to the NFPA.  If you want your inspector to "let you do that" talk to them.  However you seem to be saying as long as the inspector doesn't see it, it doesn't matter.

Comment: After talking to L&I inspector. They come out & inspect the conduit in trench prior to burying it before any other work is done if you need it. Panel does not need to be there to bury conduit and pull wire. I want to get that done since I am doing this in stages & I don't have my panels yet. You feed cable though knockout and put conduit with adaptor on end into knockout. I have seen it done. It's easier to feed a few feet though the knockout with adapter installed then feeding 175ft though it. Why is it a code violation? As long as complete run is buried when project completed for inspection

Comment: OK, i see what you are saying. I'll check with the inspector if I can do it the way I am saying. If not, I will leave the ends off while pulling I will only pull wire up to that point and only pull remaining wire though after I have the sweep and final pipe on for connection to panel. I'll run that by the inspector and make sure he is cool with it.

Comment: Sorry I may have deleted a comment by accident, refresh is real weird today.  I hear you, but if you don't even have the panel yet, what good is the wire?  It's just a theft magnet.  Harper's Law: buy the wire LAST, I wouldn't even own the wire until the last panel was bolted up. The reason you saw a contractor do that WAS NOT ease of assembly, it was to prove completion of work to get paid. The finish installer *should have* pulled the wires back out a couple feet before installing the panel. But your local AHJ is the final word on the subject.

Comment: I was just going to message and say, maybe I'll wait to pull the wire until I have the meter mounted. Makes sense, I just want to get one more thing done and out of the way if I can. Thank you for the great advise. You have been very helpful on servers topics on here.

Comment: Do you think i should pull though assembled conduit & meter panel to transformer or from transformer to meter? transformer end will be left open for PUD to hookup after installation is bought off by L&I

Comment: @Dean I'd play it by ear, based on the logistics, stuff in the boxes, viable pull angles (e.g. a tree to hook a come-along to), which end will be easiest to guide the wires into without hitting stuff, whether parts of the boxes are energized, etc.